# I want to perform text formatting in YAML

Tags: yaml

I am working on oracle chat bot and need formatted output string
For example

```
“This is a book”
```

In the above string only the word ‘book’ should appear in bold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something like that, you can only use YAML to store the text. The formatting, and the way to emphasis **book** is up to the program that interprets the data loaded from YAML.

If all the occurences of `book` should be boldened you could use a YAML file looking like:

```
bold:
- book
text: |
    This is a book
```

with the proper interpretation of the root-level mapping.

Alternatively you could apply formatting like ReST or markdown, to the loaded text In that case your YAML could even be a root level scalar:

```
--- |
This is a **book**
```

I use multi-document formats like that combining ReST, code and output to generate package documentation and for rendering stackoverflow answers that include program output.

Answer (score 2):

use safeHTML in the html file.
In yaml you can use html tags and that content will print in html as

```
{{safeHTML value}}
```

value: "This is <b> a Book</b>"

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your tag like:

```rb
t('.this_is_a_book_html')
```

And then in the config/locales:

```rb
en:
  this_is_a_book_html: 'This is a <b>book</b>
```

Also if you want to add a variable, you can do something like:

```rb
t('.this_is_an_object_html', object: 'Book')
```

```rb
en:
  this_is_an_object_html: 'This is a <b>%{object}</b>'
```